# Open Api $ref to use url

Tags: java, json, swagger, jsonschema, openapi

I have a problem to use open api v3 $ref to call a URL

I wrote an open api v3 specification to have documentation for a REST app. I am using $ref to validate the input parameters of this documentation.
These $refs are pointing to an json schema in a url.

This is an example of the apen api documentation:

(doc.yml)

```
  /myapi:
      get:
        description: Some Description
        parameters:
          - name: profile
            in: query
            description: Some description
            required: false
            schema:
              $ref: 'http://localhost:8089/refs#/properties/profile'
```

The endpoint http://localhost:8089/refs#/properties/profile is returning

```
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Some Example",
        "definitions": {},
        "properties": {
            "profile": {
                "default": "",
                "examples": [
                    "1.0.0"
                ],
                "pattern": "^(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)$",
                "type": "string",
                "title": "This is a version",
                "$id": "#/properties/profile"
            }
        },
        "$id": "myid1"
    }
```

I copy and pasted the doc.yml in the swagger and the input is validated and everything works perfect.

Due to changes in the endpoint (http://localhost:8089/refs)

I'm receiving this response:

```
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "id1"
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "description": "Some Description",
  "type": "object",
  "$id": "someid",
  "definitions": {
    "id1": {
      "description": "Some description",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Some Example",
      "properties": {
        "profile": {
          "default": "",
          "examples": [
            "1.0.0"
          ],
          "pattern": "^(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)$",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "The Version Schema",
          "$id": "#/properties/profile"
        }
      },
      "$id": "id1"
    }
  }
}
```

After this change, Swagger is throwing this error.

"Could not resolve pointer #/properties/profile"

My questions are.
Is it possible to keep using the #/properties/profile as id when the schema is using oneOf?
How can I make open api to validate the input if the json schema is using oneOf? Do I have to use another path rather that #/properties/profile?

Comment: Hi James. I'm struggling to fully understand your problem. Could you re-read and check that you've included everything you've meant to include, and the formatting and story / explanation is correct please?

Comment: Additionally, you should note that you cannot simply use JSON Schema draft-7 in OpenAPI specification files, neither directly or by referencing. This may change for OAS 3.1. You might just be lucky so far that you haven't used anything that's unsupported (I can't remember the list without looking it up).

Comment: Further, as I currently can't help with your specific question, you may find this section of the draft-7 specification document useful to understand how dereferencing works in JSON Schema when you're using location-independent identifiers: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-01#section-8.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that *Open API uses it's own flavor of JSON Schema*. It leaves some things out, adds some things, and modifies somethings. Currently, Open API does not support `$id`/`id` (Reference: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/keywords/). The good news is that you weren't using `$id` in any meaningful way, so just leaving it out doesn't change your situation.

Your `$ref: 'http://localhost:8089/refs#/properties/profile'` doesn't work anymore because that path doesn't exist anymore. The structure of the document has changed, so the JSON Pointer fragment has to use the new structure. It would have to be `$ref: 'http://localhost:8089/refs#/definitions/id1/properties/profile'`

Comment: can you please suggest if we can use bitbucket url of resource in $ref? if yes how to provide username and password required for basic authorization for accessing bitbucket url.